# Haskell more complex predicate

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell, and I'm wondering how to have a predicate that's a bit more complex.

For example, I can do this:

```
 any ( >= 5 ) my_list
```

But I can't find a way how to do something like this:

```
 any (x `mod` 2  == 0) my_list
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Third possibility, composition of operator sections, ``any ((== 0) . (`mod` 2))``. Of course that particular example should be `any even`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lambda functions:

```
any (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0) my_list
```

Answer (score 5):

For really complex stuff, you are better off, defining a separate function. For smaller cases, you could use a lambda or even something like

```
    any predicate myList
            where predicate x = even x
```

EDIT: even x is just a simplification. You could put something like `where predicate x = (mod x 3) == 1`

Comment: My favorite for non trivial cases.

Answer (score 3):

As well as using anonymous (lambda) functions as in @m0nhawk's answer, you could use function composition:

```
>>> any ( (==0) . (`mod` 2) ) [1,2,3]
True
```